# Dialogflow: Is this being used in an async call

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm new to the javascript world and have been tinkering with Actions on Google. I had an action that was previously running but after attempting to simplify my code, I've been running into a new error I cannot seem to figure out. The code is supposed to make a call to a database and return information to the user based on the date they have selected.

Problem:
The code is supposed to make a call to a database and return information to the user based on the date they have selected. The intent seems to break down when I call the URL using axios. When I test my function I receive the following error from the Google Cloud Platform: "Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?"

```js
app.intent('Moon', (conv, {date}) => {
  // Sets date to today if none given
  if (!date) {
    date = new Date().toISOString();
  }
  // Slices date string to match date format in database
  const dateSlice = date.slice(5, 9);
  // Call to row in dabase for the given date
  function getData() {
    return axios.get(`example.com/search?Date=${dateSlice}`);
  }
  return getData().then(res => {
    res.data.map(con => {
      conv.ask(`On X date there will be a ${con.Object1}`);
    });
  });
});
```

I don't know much about Promise and await but that seems to be the issue. I'm not sure how I was able to get my code to run before without these objects. I've tried to insert a Promise object before my return but it makes the rest of the function unreachable. I also checked to see if Axios had any updates but it has not, I am on the latest version. Does the error have to do with one of the returns perhaps?

Comment: Try combining the sentences into a single one, then calling `conv.close(sentence);` maybe? Also there's a typo maybe: `${dataSlice}` should be `${dateSlice}`; it could be the axios request is simply failing

Comment: You were correct to point out the typo. If fixed it in the example but that was just an error I made when copying the code into Stack Overflow; my actual code did not have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *could* be related to Promises, but you seem to be handling them correctly.

- The call to `axios.get()` is returning a Promise...
- ... which you are returning in `getData()`...
- ... which is returned in the 'Moon' Intent handler as part of the `getData().then()` block.

I suspect more that this is a logic problem. If `res.data` is an empty array, then there will be no calls to `conv.ask()`, so you end up not asking anything.

There is also a problem if `res.data` has more than two items. In this case, you'll generate an error because you've replied with more than two "simple" responses.

Either way - you may wish to log `res` and/or `res.data` to make sure you're getting back what you think.

Comment: You were correct `res.data` was returning an empty array. This was actually due to the way I sliced the array. The end parameter in the `slice` method goes up to, but does not include, the given position. So in my case the ISO string was being cut at "05-1", instead of "05-10".

Appreciate the help!